# mysql service start time

Tags: python, mysql

Is there any variables in mysql that will return the date on which mysql service was started?
I am using following 4 steps to get the mysql start date.

```
mysql> select now(), unix_timestamp(now());
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| now()               | unix_timestamp(now()) |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2014-08-31 12:14:09 |            1409467449 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+

mysql> show status like 'uptime';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Uptime        | 242645 |
+---------------+--------+

mysql> select (1409467449  - 242645 );
+-------------------------+
| (1409467449  - 242645 ) |
+-------------------------+
|              1409224804 |
+-------------------------+

mysql> SELECT from_unixtime(1409224804 );
+----------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1409224804 ) |
+----------------------------+
| 2014-08-28 16:50:04        |
+----------------------------+
```

Is there any way to write a stored procedure or function that will return the server start time?

I need to use this date in python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select date_sub(now(), INTERVAL variable_value SECOND) started_at
from information_schema.global_status 
where variable_name='Uptime';
```